# git checkout <branch> -- path/to/file not working

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

When I try to replace a file in a branch with the version from the master branch it acts as if it worked; however, the file is not replaced and nothing new is staged. For example, here is a sample workflow:

```
git checkout someBranch
git checkout master -- path/to/file
```

The second command will return as if nothing went wrong or nothing has happened. How do I checkout a file from a different branch into my current branch?

Comment: Are you sure the file differs between the two branches?

Comment: @ifconfig The op didn't say that, just said that it acted as if it worked, like nothing happened.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, I am positive they are different. I did a git fetch to make sure my local branch was synced with the remote. I'm not positive if that had any affect because checkout pulls from the remote anyways right?

Comment: @inafalcao Yup. I read it wrong.

Comment: What's the output of `git diff master someBranch path/to/file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the commit id instead of the branch name.

From the man page:

```
git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...
```

> When  or --patch are given, git checkout does **not** switch
>   branches. It updates the named paths in the working tree from the
>   index and file or from a named <tree-ish> (most often a commit). In
>   this case, the **-b** and **--track** options are meaningless; giving either of
>   them results in an error. The <tree-ish> argument can be used to
>   specify a specific tree-ish (i.e. commit, tag or tree) to update the
>   index for the given paths before updating the working tree.

Comment: Awesome this worked, thank you. The man page is now clear, I missed the i.e. for tree-ish

Comment: Even I was under the impression that branch name and commit id are interchangeable; but it seems that that's not always the case. With something like Git, man pages are invaluable. :)